# Unresolved reference : uiMode I saveToDataStore

Tags: android, kotlin, debugging, unresolved-external

I am a beginner in programming, and I am facing a problem with this group of codes, and I cannot understand the problem and solve it, knowing that the code is ready, not written by me

```
package www.spikeysanju.jetquotes.view


import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import www.spikeysanju.jetquotes.data.preference.UIModeImpl
import www.spikeysanju.jetquotes.navigation.NavGraph
import www.spikeysanju.jetquotes.ui.JetQuotesTheme

import www.spikeysanju.jetquotes.R


@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var uiModeDataStore: UIModeImpl

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        this.setContent {
            JetQuotesMain()
        }
        // observe theme change
        observeUITheme()
```

[image]

[image]

[[image]] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f7pm.jpg)

Comment: I think you should go through some beginner tutorials. Otherwise we will just be wasting our time repeating what the tutorials will already tell you. You can’t declare a variable that has no type and you can’t arbitrarily use properties of some specific class anywhere you like outside that class.

Comment: First, I apologize, and I am not trying to waste your time. I know very well the value of the time of every professional programmer here, but as I explained, I am a beginner and I am not the one who wrote the code, and these errors in this code are the only obstacle that stands before me now in order to publish the application in the store, and I need I strongly publish the app as soon as possible so I saw a request for help here and fix the code for me.

Comment: I still can't solve the problem, can you help me? I just want to complete the application and publish it
I sincerely apologize for the inconvenience, but I am really stuck and things are blurry for me @Tenfour04

Comment: I don’t understand how you can write a whole application, much less a hello-world, without knowing how to declare a variable. I can’t take the time to walk you through the beginner tutorials step by step all the way up to building a working app, sorry. You might have better luck on a message board or Discord channel where you’re allowed to have a conversation. It’s off topic on this site. This problem isn’t as simple as telling you the correct syntax. We would have to discuss back and forth what exactly the code must do in detail, which you won’t be able to explain since you didn’t write it.